# Yet again: getting mouse coordinates after click on an image for mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

After clicking on an image on some point, I want to get the x and y coordinates of that point woth respect to the top left corner of the image.

After googling and stackoverflowing a bit, I find this solution with jquery.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<body>
<!-- WEBSITE CONTENT -->
<img src="image.jpg" id="test">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function(e) {
               var offset = $('#test').offset();
               var x=e.pageX - offset.left;
               var y=e.pageY - offset.top;
               alert(x+' '+y);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, this code seems to work very well on non-mobile devices but it has problems on *some* mobile devices, in the sense that it does not return the right coordinates (at least pageY). On the other hand, even other solutions (based on the use of screenX/Y) seems to have problems on mobile devices.

So, I'm wondering:

1) somebody knows a robust solution working for mobile? Or,

2) somebody knows a workaround to at least detect if the mobile device does not correctly interpret the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe page is scaled.When in windows, it return (2,2) maybe on mobile it return(1,1).

Comment: Maybe. In that case, do you know if a "page scale ratio (with respect to the standard/initial positioning)" is known/accessible in some variable?

Comment: I just know in people can get te scale in  Android Webview . or you can try get width of page.

Comment: Good hint I'm trying that. Thanks